# Javascript Date to String Conversion

Tags: javascript

I have string `02-APR-15 11:08 AM` which i have to convert DateTime format in javascript.I am used

```
var date = Date.parse('02-APR-15 11:08 AM');
alert(date);
```

which shows `NaN` .How to convert this string to DateTime Format.

Comment: You need to format the date at first. Better use `moment.js` for date manipulation

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputDate='02-APR-15 11:08 AM';
inputDate =inputDate.replace(/-/g, ' ');
var result = new Date(inputDate);
alert(result);
```

Comment: this too will not work in FF. This alerts invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

Correct it will not work in FF. Have a look at this code.

```
var dateString = '02-APR-2015 11:08 AM';
var d = dateString.split(" ");
dArray = d[0].split("-");
var day = dArray[0];
var month = dArray[1];
switch(dArray[1]) {
    case "JAN" :
        month = "01";
        break;
    case "FEB" :
        month = "02";
        break;
    case "MAR" :
        month = "03";
        break;
    case "APR" :
        month = "04";
        break;
    case "MAY" :
        month = "05";
        break;
    case "JUN" :
        month = "06";
        break;
    case "JUL" :
        month = "07";
        break;
    case "AUG" :
        month = "08";
        break;
    case "SEP" :
        month = "09";
        break;
    case "OCT" :
        month = "10";
        break;
    case "NOV" :
        month = "11";
        break;
    case "DEC" :
        month = "12";
        break;
    default :
        month = "01";
        break;        
}
var year = dArray[2];
var tm = d[1].split(":");
    if(d[2] == "AM") {
        var tm_h = tm[0];
   } else {
       var tm_h = tm[1]+12;
   }
   var tm_m = tm[1];
       var newStr = year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"T"+tm_h+":"+tm_m+":"+"00";

var date = new Date(newStr);
alert(date);
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uuv7uv3h/

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = Date.parse(response.date);
alert(date.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
date = new Date('02-APR-15 11:08 AM');
alert(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse` returns a `timestamp` which is an integer when a valid date string is supplied, otherwise NaN. So you need to convert your date string to a valid string like:

```
var s = '02-APR-15 11:08 AM'.replace(/(\d{1,2})-(\w+)-(\d{2})/, '$2 $1 20$3')
date = new Date(s);
```